# Invalid bracketing of name

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm getting an error `Invalid bracketing of name [qryTemp.IEnduseID]`

```sql
strSQL = "SELECT tbl_Item_Enduse.IEnduseID, tbl_Item_Enduse.IEnduseDesc, IIf([qryTemp.IEnduseID]>0,-1,0) AS Sel " & _
    "FROM tbl_Item_Enduse LEFT JOIN (SELECT tbl_ItemsEU.EUid FROM tbl_ItemsEU " & _
    "WHERE tbl_ItemsEU.ItemID=" & Nz(Me.ItemID, 0) & ")  AS qryTemp " & _
    "ON tbl_Item_Enduse.IEnduseID = qryTemp.EUid " & _
    "ORDER BY tbl_Item_Enduse.IEnduseDesc;"
```

If I remove the bracket - I'm getting 'Too few parameters ...

Please help.

Comment: You have two I's on your If statement. Is that the issue? `IIf([qryTemp.IEnduseID]>0,-1,0)`

Comment: Remove the square brackets from `[qryTemp.IEnduseID]`.

Comment: @Hoppo: [Iif](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) is access syntax.

Comment: Try `[qryTemp].[IEnduseID]`. Each object gets its own set of quotes. Both the table and column. Otherwise it's looking for a column named "qryTemp.IEnduseID"

Comment: @forpas: Indeed, it should read (when using brackets) `[qryTemp].[IEnduseID]` or (without brackets): `qryTemp.IEnduseID`.

Comment: @BillJetzer - thanks for the response -I'm getting error 'Too few parameteres. Expected 1. on that suggestion :(

Answer (score 1):

From your `JOIN` expression, consider using `EuId` instead of `IEnduseID` since former is referenced in subquery you aliased as `qdyTemp`. Otherwise, referencing the latter column will result in unknown paramters. Consider also, shorter table aliases for compact readability.

```
strSQL = "SELECT t.IEnduseID, t.IEnduseDesc, " & _
         "       IIf([q.EUid]>0,-1,0) AS Sel " & _ 
         "FROM tbl_Item_Enduse AS t" & _
         "LEFT JOIN " & _
         " (SELECT sub.EUid " & _
         "  FROM tbl_ItemsEU sub " & _ 
         "  WHERE sub.ItemID=" & Nz(Me.ItemID, 0) & ") AS q " & _ 
         "ON t.IEnduseID = q.EUid " & _ 
         "ORDER BY t.IEnduseDesc;"
```

By the way, not sure how you are using above dynamic query from SQL string, but consider a saved query that will be more efficient with `JOIN` as engine saves best execution plan. Also, saved queries can directly use open form controls. Doing so you also avoid messy VBA concatenation.

```sql
SELECT t.IEnduseID, t.IEnduseDesc,
       IIF([q.EUid]>0,-1,0) AS Sel
FROM tbl_Item_Enduse AS t
LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT sub.EUid
      FROM tbl_ItemsEU sub
      WHERE sub.ItemID = Nz(Forms!myOpenForm!ItemID, 0) AS q
ON t.IEnduseID = q.EUid
ORDER BY t.IEnduseDesc;
```

In VBA, stored queries with GUI parameters can be used in multiple ways involving GUI operations (i.e., forms, reports).

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedQuery"

Me.Form.RecordSource = "mySavedQuery"
Me.Form.Requery

Me.myComboOrListBox.RowSource = "" 
Me.myComboOrListBox.RowSource = "mySavedQuery"
Me.myComboOrListBox.Requery
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up field names.

Try with (just guessing):

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT tbl_Item_Enduse.IEnduseID, tbl_Item_Enduse.IEnduseDesc, IIf(qryTemp.IEnduseID>0,-1,0) AS Sel " & _
    "FROM tbl_Item_Enduse LEFT JOIN (SELECT tbl_ItemsEU.EUid As IEnduseID FROM tbl_ItemsEU " & _
    "WHERE tbl_ItemsEU.ItemID=" & Nz(Me.ItemID, 0) & ")  AS qryTemp " & _
    "ON tbl_Item_Enduse.IEnduseID = qryTemp.IEnduseID " & _
    "ORDER BY tbl_Item_Enduse.IEnduseDesc;"
```